# Daylight saving time causing issues in our system

Tags: java, dst

I am into a conflict. I have a schedule that generates 24 hour schedule but the thing is, on NOV 3rd at 2AM the time will change from 2AM to 1AM, means subtracting an hr. How can I handle that thing in Java. The schdule which I get from thrid party say...

1. 01: 05 AM (1st Show)
2. 01: 05 AM (2nd Show)
3. 03: 05 AM (3rd Show) and so on.

The 2nd show should be 2:05 but due to time change it's 1:05. Same timing causing exception. Please help me how to handle this scenario.

Thanks

---

Below is the error I am getting while generating PDF schedule using XSL document in Apache FOP.

```
     Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 450, Size: 421
     at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
     at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.table.ColumnSetup.getXOffset(ColumnSetup.java:224)
     at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.table.TableContentLayoutManager.getXOffsetOfGridUnit(
     TableContentLayoutManager.java:603) at              
     org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.table.TableContentLayoutManager$RowPainter.
    addAreasForCell(TableContentLayoutManager.java:981)
at   org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.table.TableContentLayoutManager$RowPainter.
    addAreasAndFlushRow
    (TableContentLayoutManager.java:943)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.table.TableContentLayoutManager$RowPainter.
    handleTableContentPosition(TableContentLayoutManager.java:800)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.table.TableContentLayoutManager.iterateAndPaintPositions
    (TableContentLayoutManager.java:754)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.table.TableContentLayoutManager.addAreas
    (TableContentLayoutManager.java:687)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.table.TableLayoutManager.addAreas
    (TableLayoutManager.java:346)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.AreaAdditionUtil.addAreas(AreaAdditionUtil.java:116)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.FlowLayoutManager.addAreas(FlowLayoutManager.java:297)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.PageSequenceLayoutManager$PageBreaker.addAreas
    (PageSequenceLayoutManager.java:356)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.AbstractBreaker.addAreas(AbstractBreaker.java:507)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.AbstractBreaker.addAreas(AbstractBreaker.java:370)
at   org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.PageSequenceLayoutManager$PageBreaker.doPhase3
    (PageSequenceLayoutManager.java:369)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.AbstractBreaker.doLayout(AbstractBreaker.java:345)
    at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.AbstractBreaker.doLayout(AbstractBreaker.java:263)
```

Only this schedule thrown an error. So My guess in it's because of the time change. Any Idea how to accomodate/fix this.

Comment: Show us what you are doing right now.

Comment: Please add code, desired results(explicit) and any stack trace for exceptions you are encountering.  Thanks.

Comment: You should understand that this problem is not related to Java but to DST. Also, there's no code that will *save* you from this, since basically November 3rd 02:00 **does not exists** for the GMT/UTC you're working with. If you want to display 2:00 AM for this day (and future), you have to build it manually as `String` or create your own representation of this time.

Comment: In general you'd want to store date/time values in UTC and convert to local time when used for local purposes (such as displaying a user's schedule).  As you're discovering, "local time" can have quirks.  So it's good to have a library that will take a standard date/time representation (UTC) and convert it to whatever the local time is, well, at that time.  There are some really handy libraries to help with conversion: http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

Comment: what exception occurs ? are you generating some file named with the hour ? what class are you using to get that hour ? Date , Calendar?

Comment: Actually, your "3rd show" would be 2:05.  The "4th show" would be 3:05.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - yes, 2:00 *does* exist.  It's just that 1:00 exists twice.  You are thinking of the spring-forward transition, this is the fall-back transition.

Comment: @MattJohnson I meant there's no 2:00 a.m. explicitly in the GMT/UTC configuration used by OP.

Answer (score 2):

> on NOV 3rd at 2AM the time will change from 2AM to 1AM, means subtracting an hr. How can I handle that thing in Java

In some places the local time will change, in others it won't.  Time itself isn't changing, just the local interpretation of that locality's representation of the "current time" (which itself remains fairly constant, or as constant as it can on this imprecisely spinning ball of rock on which we live).

The point is, you shouldn't have to subtract anything.  Because nothing in the underlying data is actually changing, only a local view of that data.

How are you storing your date/time values?  If you're not using [UTC time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) for your underlying data, you should be.  For the reason you're currently facing, as well as other very similar reasons which would create other very similar problems.  The point is to separate the actual data being stored from any particular user's view of that data.

With underlying date/time data stored in a universal format, you can convert it on the fly when needed, usually for display purposes.  (Sometimes for local calculations as well.)  Libraries like [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) are really useful for that, and tons of time and effort have been put into understanding and solving the problem you currently face.